# Is the `bv_len` field of `struct bio_vec` necessarily a multiple of the device's sector size?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, block-device

Assuming we are reading data from the device, if the `bio_vec` contains a contiguous segment in memory where to data can be written by the driver, is the `bvec->len` field a multiple of our device's sector (or better yet, a multiple of a block)?

In case it's not, should the driver create memory regions where the data should be written by the device, and only then write `len` bytes to the `page + offset` address of the `bio_vec` struct?